# Preincrement and Postincrement

Tags: c++, increment, post-increment, pre-increment

I've been trying to understand how post and pre increments work lately and I've been over thinking it too much.

Does "Product" become 25 after one iteration?

```
Product *=5++
```

And does "Quotient" become 5/6 after one iteration?

```
Quotient /= ++x
```

Comment: Have you even tried compiling this?!

Comment: `5++` doesn't make sense. Why wouldn't you just write `6`?

Answer (score 2):

`5++` is just incorrect.

`Quotient /= ++x;` is the same as `x = x + 1; Quotient = Quotient / x;` (assuming these are just plain numbers).

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't valid C++, since the built-in post-increment operator may only be applied to lvalues, but literal integers are rvalues.

Beside that, the value of a (built-in) pre-increment expression is the incremented value, while the value of a post-increment expression is the original value.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-increment modifies the variable and evaluates to the modified value.

Post-increment evaluates to the value of the variable and then increments the variable.

```
int a = 5;
int b = ++a; // a = a + 1; b = a
int c = a++; // c = a; a = a + 1
```

Consider these simple implementations of ++ for int

```
int& int::preincrement()
{
    this->m_value += 1;
    return *this;
}

int int::postincrement()
{
    int before = this->m_value;
    this->m_value += 1;
    return before;
}
```

Comment: Just an obligatory warning to those who might get the idea, `int` is definitely not a class.